# How to find an exact value in an Excel sheet

Tags: vbscript

How could I find a string value in an excel sheet. 
I am trying `objRange.Find()` but this give me the wrong address too. As example i want the address of 'Object_paint' but it gives also the address of 'Object_paint_and_stk'

How should i get only exact value..?

```
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet)
Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("B2:B600")    
Set objFind = objRange.Find("object_paint")

If Not objFind Is Nothing Then
    searchValue = objFind.AddressLocal(False, False)
end if
```

Comment: can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First hit for

```
excel range.find exact match site:microsoft.com
```

is:

[Range.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find.ASPX)

There you find

> LookAt
>       Type: System.Object
>
> ```
> Optional Object. Can be one of the following XlLookAt constants: xlWhole or xlPart.
> ```

and following the [LookAt link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xllookat.ASPX), you see:

```
xlPart  Match against any part of the search text.
xlWhole Match against the whole of the search text.
```

BTW: Who is objTarget?

**Update:**

You have to 'port' (some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info)) the VBA code snippet you mention in your comment to VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

' Define Excel Consts unknown to VBScript
Const xlPart  = 2 
Const xlWhole = 1 

Dim oExcel : Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oWBook : Set oWBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\ut.xls")
Dim oRange : Set oRange = oWBook.Sheets("NewSheet").Range("A1:A11")
' translate named args to positional args
' expression.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte)
Dim oFnd1  : Set oFnd1  = oRange.Find("Title1", , , xlPart)
WScript.Echo TypeName(oFnd1), CStr(oFnd1)
Dim oFnd2  : Set oFnd2  = oRange.Find("Title1", , , xlWhole)
WScript.Echo TypeName(oFnd2), CStr(oFnd2)

oWBook.Close
oExcel.Quit
```

output:

```
cscript excelfind.vbs
Range Title10
Range Title1
```

Comment: BTW: Who is objTarget? :
it should be objFind. sorry for the inconvenient (edited)

Comment: I found this.
"Find(what:="Value", lookat:=xlWhole)".
Is this i should looking for. but i failed when i tried to apply it for vbscript.